# ajax returns json with added character

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a Jquery code getting data from ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'php/upd_dashboard.php',
data: {'name': 'GET_ANUAL_TOTAL_OBJECTIF'},
success: function(data){

    list_total_objectif=data;
},
dataType: 'JSON',
async: false
```

});

the file upd_dashboard.php, get data from MySql database, and return json result.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

I have no problem when executing this code in localhost, but when I deploy the site I can't get the result of json_encode.
by inspecting that in Chrome, I get a character '\ufeff' at the beginning of the json result !!

[Chrome inspection result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPNUZ.png)

Is it a problem of encoding?
Regards,
Hamza.

Comment: Please show `upd_dashboard.php` code

Comment: May be many things. Something similar happened to me when I had the source files in UTF-8 (With BOM). If I'm not wrong some versions of PHP didn't like the BOM thing and were adding some weird character at the begining. Try converting all your soruce files to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: <?php 

require_once("../functions.php");

switch ($_GET['name']) {
 case 'GET_ANUAL_TOTAL_OBJECTIF':
  
  $sql="SELECT obj_annee, obj_target, obj_accomplish FROM objectif";
  $result=selectRows($sql);
  
 break;
}

echo json_encode($result);

 ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try doing ob_clean(); before sending out json output

```
ob_clean();//clears the output buffer
echo json_encode($result);
```

But it seems your $result is just malformed. Is it a string or an array? No character encoding issues there anyway

Comment: The return is an array, I tried with ob_clean() but still having the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749384/web-server-response-generates-utf-8-bom-json It really seems there is some file in your project it goes through and it's encoded with BOM as Robert suggested

Comment: Strange, with ob_clean() it solved my problem, thank you for you help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found on Google, \ufeff is the Byte Order Mark.

So you probably have your PHP source files in UTF-8 With BOM.

Some PHP versions don't like that and send the BOM output.

Try converting all your PHP source files to UTF-8 Without BOM and it should fix the issue.

Comment: All php my php source are saved in UTF-8 Without BOM.